# Missing AppPackageUrl: NSIS-Web configuration with electron-builder

Tags: vue.js, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I am currently building a VueJS application with Electron. For this I use the dependency "electron-builder". There is relatively detailed documentation on "https://www.electron.build/", but there is one detail that I am missing and just can't figure out - even after several hours of googling.

Here's the scenario:

I want to build an NSIS web installer instead of a normal NSIS installer. I can get the "normal" installer to work. For the web installer I have defined the following configuration in my "electron-builder.json5":

```
/**
 * @see https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration
 */
{
  "appId": "com.emhartglass.flexis",
  "productName": "FlexFire",
  "copyright": "Copyright © year ${author}",
  "asar": true,
  "icon": "build/bucher-logo-small-512x512.ico",
  "directories": {
    "output": "release/${version}"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist-electron",
    "dist"
  ],
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis-web",
        // ...
        "arch": [
          "x64"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}.${ext}",
  },
  "nsis": {
    //
    "oneClick": false,
    //
    "perMachine": false,
    //
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
    //
    "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
    //
    "unicode": true,
    //
    "menuCategory": true,
    //
    "createDesktopShortcut": true,
    //
    "displayLanguageSelector": true,
    //
    "shortcutName": "FlexFire",
    //
    "installerIcon": "build/bucher-logo-small-512x512.ico",
    //
    "uninstallerIcon": "build/bucher-logo-small-512x512.ico",
    //
    "installerHeader": "build/bucher-header.bmp",
    //
    "installerHeaderIcon": "build/bucher-logo-small-512x512.ico",
    //
    "installerSidebar": "build/bucher-sidebar-installer.bmp",
    //
    "uninstallerSidebar": "build/bucher-sidebar-uninstaller.bmp",
    //
    "uninstallDisplayName": "${productName} ${version}",
    //
    "license": "build/license/license_en.txt",
    // ...
    "multiLanguageInstaller": true,
    //
    "packElevateHelper": true
  }
}
```

Now that I have triggered the build process, it is aborted with the following error:

"Cannot compute app package download URL failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Cannot compute app package download URL".

I have no idea where I define this link and what else I may need, if I don't already know. The documentation here is almost non-existent after all. Does anyone here know anything about this?

Thank you very much,
Dennis

I have so far found the tag "appPackageUrl" on another page and put it in different places after the brackets, but nowhere has it resulted in success.

If you put a wrong tag in a place and trigger the build process, then an error message comes up that it doesn't know the tag and what tags are possible. Even with the options given I have not found a tag that might make me smarter.

I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are customizing the installer using the "nsis" key, while the
[NSIS electron-builder page](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#web-installer) tells that
"To customize web installer, use the top-level nsisWeb key (not nsis)."
That should be the reason why it does not find appPackageUrl: try to change "nsis" to "nsisWeb"